# Use custom domain for AWS WorkMail webmail access url

Tags: amazon-workmail

I am able to set up AWS WorkMail to receive and send email using custom domain e.g. `john@mycompany.com`

Now I'd like to allow our users to login and access emails at `https://mail.mycompany.com`  (instead of the AWS provided access url `https://mycompany.awsapps.com`).

The [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workmail/latest/adminguide/domains_overview.html) I can find seems only handle my first case (which is already done).

Thanks

Comment: you're still active, did any of these answers work for you?

Answer (score 8):

I would create a static s3 page with a basic html redirect if you already have the domain name in route 53.  That way it is free.

1. Create a new s3bucket, `mywebmail.mydomain.com`
2. in the s3 bucket properties turn on **static domain hosting**
3. create an `index.html` page with the following code:

```html
<html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='https://mydomain.com.awsapps.com/mail'" />
 </head>
</html>
```

4. go to route53 and create a new record set.  Select alias and find your s3 bucket created in step 1.

S3 Static websites are pretty powerful stuff. I love them!

Answer (score 6):

I resolved this by using the built-in CloudFront interface.

I admit the documentation on this is pretty poor, but the aim behind it is to get people to pay for this redirection.

To have your **mywebmail.mydomain.com mapped** into **myaws.awsapps.com/workmail** then please follow the steps below:

1) You might have done this step already: On your DNS server (where that is), create a CNAME to map mywebmail.mydomain.com into myaws.awsapps.com

2) Login into your CloudFront interface https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/

3) Click on "Create Distribution"

4) On the Origin-Domain put myaws.awsapps.com

5) On the Origin-URI put /workmail

6) Adjust the setting to what you like such as redirecting from HTTP into HTTPS or use as-is etc.

7) Scroll down to the CNAME and enter the aliases you need, for this example you need to put in mywebmail.mydomain.com

8) Save

9) Notice that this might take a while to get created, mine took about 30 minutes to complete, also every time I needed to edit something it would take around 10-20 minutes to complete.

10) Once done, browse your mywebmail.mydomain.com, your CNAME on your original DNS (step 1 above) should ask your browser to redirect and then with AWS CloundFront setting it would add the URI afterwards,

11) If you get a blank page, then check your headers, in particular ( ?organization=YourDomainName ), you might need to manually add it there from the behaviours menu of the item you created above.

Comment: In step one I create a CNAME from mywebmail.mydomain.com to myaws.awsapps.com/workmail . However setting up the cloudfront distribution with origin myaws.awsapps.com and CNAME mywebmail.mydomain.com is doing te same thing isn't it?

Comment: @xtra How is it possible to create a CNAME record that points to a subdirectory? You'd have to add `/workmail` after your custom domain, however, with CloudFront distribution, you don't have to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Create a sub-domain "mail.mycompany.com" and redirect it to "mycompany.awsapps.com".

Comment: Do you mean create a CNAME form "mail.mycompany.com" to "mycompany.awsapps.com"?

Comment: I don't think that CNAME creates a redirection to mycompany.awsapps.com.

Answer (score 1):

You can now set S3 to redirect without hosting anything in it.

1. Create a bucket `mail.yourdomain.com`
2. Under properties enable `Static website hosting`
   [image: setting is at the bottom of the page]
3. Under hosting `Redirect requests for an object` set hostname to `yourcompanyname.awsapps.com/mail`
   [image: screenshot of setting]
4. under Route53 create an alias A record that points to the S3 bucket